# Datatable.DefaultView.RowFilter not functioning for certain users

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

So I am at my wits end. I am at the point of releasing this program, but currently I am the only user that can open it. I have switched the SQL database from Windows Authentication to SQL Server Authentication as I thought this was an issue with the SQL server not allowing other users the ability to connect. I am able to get this to function for all users when I only filter the main table (see DashboardDataFiltersub) but if I use any of the other filters all I get is the splash screen, then the application closes. The strange part to me is if I comment or remove FixtureDataFilter, ProgramDataFilter & CMMDataFilter this program will function without any issues.

Thank you for your help,
Matt

```
Imports System.Data
Imports SPR.DatabaseLoading
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class OpenScreen
    Public Shared OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim User As String = Environment.UserName & "@senioraeroct.com"
    Dim Result() As DataRow

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        SPRMainDataAdapt.Fill(SPRMainDataTable)
        ProgramDataAdapt.Fill(ProgramDataTable)
        FixtureDataAdapt.Fill(FixtureDataTable)
        CMMDataAdapt.Fill(CMMDataTable)

        Dim SPRSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(FindResource("SPRSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
        SPRSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()
        DashBoardDataGrid.ItemsSource = SPRMainDataTable

        Dim ProgSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(FindResource("ProgSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
        ProgSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()
        ProgramDataGrid.ItemsSource = ProgramDataTable

        Dim FixSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(FindResource("FixSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
        FixSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()
        FixtureDataGrid.ItemsSource = FixtureDataTable

        Dim CMMSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(FindResource("CMMSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
        CMMSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()
        CMMDataGrid.ItemsSource = CMMDataTable

        ComboDataAdapt.FillEmail(EmailDataTable)
        Result = EmailDataTable.Select("Email = '" & User & "'")

        If Result.Length <> 0 Then
            User = Result(0)("Name")
        End If

        DashboardDataFilter()
        FixtureDataFilter()
        ProgramDataFilter()
        CMMDataFilter()
        OpenBtn.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_Initialized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized
        Try
            OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        Catch
            OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub DashboardDataFilter()
        'Set the filter based on username
        Dim Filter As String = ""

        If Result.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim Type As String = Result(0)("Type")
            If Type.Contains("Engineering") Then
                If Type.Contains("Quality Engineering") Then
                    Filter = Filter & "CompleteSPR is NULL AND QualName LIKE '%" & User & "%'"
                Else
                    Filter = Filter & "CompleteSPR is NULL AND EngName LIKE '%" & User & "%'"
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Filter = Filter & "EngName LIKE '%N/A%'"
        End If

        'Apply Filter
        SPRMainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = Filter
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgramDataFilter()
        'Set the filter based on username
        Dim Filter As String = ""

        Filter = "Complete is NULL"
        If Result.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim Type As String = Result(0)("Type")
            If Type.Contains("Engineering") Then
                If Type.Contains("Quality Engineering") = False Then
                    Filter = Filter & " AND (SPREng LIKE '%" & User & "%')"
                End If
            End If
            Filter = Filter & " OR (AssignedBy LIKE '%" & User & "%' OR Programmer LIKE '%" & User & "%')"
        Else
            Filter = Filter & " AssignedBy LIKE '%N/A%'"
        End If

        'Apply Filter
        ProgramDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = Filter
    End Sub

    Private Sub FixtureDataFilter()
        'Set the filter based on username
        Dim Filter As String = ""

        Filter = "Complete is NULL"
        If Result.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim Type As String = Result(0)("Type")
            If Type.Contains("Engineering") Then
                If Type.Contains("Quality Engineering") = False Then
                    Filter = Filter & " AND (SPREng LIKE '%" & User & "%')"
                End If
            End If
            Filter = Filter & " OR (AssignedBy LIKE '%" & User & "%' OR DesEng LIKE '%" & User & "%')"
        Else
            Filter = Filter & " AssignedBy LIKE '%N/A%'"
        End If

        'Apply Filter
        FixtureDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = Filter
    End Sub

    Private Sub CMMDataFilter()
        'Set the filter based on username
        Dim Filter As String = ""

        Filter = "Complete is NULL"
        If Result.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim Type As String = Result(0)("Type")
            If Type.Contains("Engineering") Then
                If Type.Contains("Quality Engineering") = False Then
                    Filter = Filter & " AND (SPREng LIKE '%" & User & "%')"
                End If
            End If
            Filter = Filter & " OR (AssignedBy LIKE '%" & User & "%' OR Programmer LIKE '%" & User & "%')"
        Else
            Filter = Filter & " AssignedBy LIKE '%N/A%'"
        End If

        'Apply Filter
        CMMDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = Filter
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I strongly recommend  some error handling and logging. Don't just fix this and walk away thinking "phew".  There could be other problems and users will lose faith if you're not careful.  In the short term. Could you possibly get a user to log on to your dev machine and see what happens. If it crashes then it's still authorities and you will be able to see the error produced.   Is there nothing in their machine logs?

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have a temp account that I am testing with on my computer along with an RDC with a few other account names for testing. As far as the error handling I will start adding it in. Thanks.

Comment: Andy, your error handler helped me find the issue. It was a syntax error in the filter where I needed to add an OR to the Filter = Filter & " AssignedBy LIKE '%N/A%'" line. Thanks for the help